# Excel unique value in range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

Hi I need to ensure the values unique in range with  if possible with a high performance way. Sample data as shown below:

```
 A                 B
1 Serial From   -   Serial To
2 364500            364600
3 326900            326940
4 120000            120300
5 154700            154800
6    460               480
```

- Table is unsorted
- There are two numbers in each row
  which always A is less than B
- I always enter    new values to next empty row

There musnt be any number  that match the  any range above. If I enter 120150 and 120700 (because of 4th row) it must give error. 
How could I do that? I use Excel 2007. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{=IF(SUM(((A6>=$A$1:A5)*(A6<=$B$1:B5))+((B6>=$A$1:A5)*(B6<=$B$1:B5)))>0,"OVERLAP","")}
```

If you put this in C6 and you put your next numbers in A6 and B6, C6 will say 'overlap' if any do.

Don't type the curly braces {}.  Instead enter the formula using control+shift+enter, because it's an array formula.

Comment: Thanks for reply. One more question: For array fomulas why autofilling formulas dont work?

Comment: Autofilling should work on array formulas just like regular formulas.